# How to load my own csv into vega-lite online editor?

Tags: vega-lite

I would like to use the online vega-lite editor to do some quick prototyping of some graphs I want to build. The examples use

```
  "data": {
    "url": "data/penguins.json"
  },
```

Is there a way to load data from a .csv file from within the editor?

Comment: You can either provide the data inline or upload your CSV file to host and link to that.

Comment: @DavideBacci How do I upload the CSV file "to host"?

Comment: You can upload anywhere. Why not open a GitHub account and store your csv there for free.

Comment: For instance, paste into https://gist.github.com/, then submit as "public", then click the "Raw" button in the upper right and use that URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a concrete example of how to load .csv data from a GitHub page. For this example, consider the "Bubble Plot (Gapminder)" example ([link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega-lite/circle_bubble_health_income)) on the online Vega editor. This example uses the following line to load data, similar to the example you provided: `"data": {"url": "data/gapminder-health-income.csv"}`. However, we can change this link to a direct GitHub link as follows.

First, find the data that you want to use on GitHub. This particular dataset is hosted on the Vega GitHub under the vega-datasets repository at this [link](https://github.com/vega/vega-datasets/blob/main/data/gapminder-health-income.csv). From this GitHub page, you can select the "raw" button to get a link to only the raw data ([link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vega/vega-datasets/main/data/gapminder-health-income.csv)), which can then be used in the online editor as follows: `"data": {"url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vega/vega-datasets/main/data/gapminder-health-income.csv"}`. The resulting visualization will be exactly the same as the default one, but this approach can work for any datasets that you host for yourself on GitHub.

[image: GitHub screenshot highlighting the "raw" button]